# Efficiently constructing related hierarchy of objects

Tags: java, algorithm

For this toy example, I have a list of Classrooms with id and name. I fetch these classrooms from a datasource and then, for each classroom, I will need students and teacher lists to be fetched. I then would like to create another object that takes in classroom.id, classroom.name and `List<Student>, List<Teacher>` called Foo. The issue being Foo is an immutable object and must be instantiated when all info is available. Here is what I have tried:

```
List<Classroom> classrooms = dataSource.fetchClassroomsById(classroomIds);
Map<Integer, Classroom> idToClassroom = new HashMap<>();
        classrooms.stream()
            .forEach(classroom -> {idToClassroom.put(classroom.getId(), classroom);});

//get all students and teachers that belong to set of classroomIds passed in
List<Student> students = dataSource.fetchStudentsById(classroomIds);
List<Teacher> teachers = dataSource.fetchTeachersById(classroomIds);

for (Student student : students) {
    //gets the classroom for which student belongs. This is where I get stuck.
    idsToClassroom.get(student.getClassRoomId())
}
...
```

Basically, how can I construct my Foo object efficiently and compactly at this point?

Comment: What is `datasource`? can you change the `datasource` code?

Comment: @sidgate no its kinda an abstraction here. Assume it cannot be changed or fiddled with. It is provided as-is

Comment: hmm.. I was thinking of updating the `fetchStudentsById` to return Map<ClassroomId, List<Students>> to make it easier

Comment: @sidgate that would be great! unfortunately, the I am just a consumer of datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group students and teachers in lists of the same classroom id.

```
List<Classroom> classrooms = dataSource.fetchClassroomsById(classroomIds);
List<Student> students = dataSource.fetchStudentsById(classroomIds);
List<Teacher> teachers = dataSource.fetchTeachersById(classroomIds);

Map<Integer, List<Student>> classroomIdToStudent = students.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getClassroomId));

Map<Integer, List<Teacher>> classroomIdToTeacher = teachers.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Teacher::getClassroomId));

List<Foo> foos = classrooms.stream().map(c -> new Foo(c.getId(), c.getName(),
    classroomIdToStudent.get(c.getId()), classroomIdToTeacher.get(c.getId()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```